# Minecraft Rescource Pack broke special characters

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been making a modified version of the vanilla 1.14 resource pack recently, and have noticed something strange. When there is any special characters shown (i.e. ♠ or •) they appear as entirely different shapes. (See attached picture.) The strange thing is, if I turn on "Font Unicode" they appear normal. However, I do not want to always have this on, as I prefer the classic text design. Does anybody know what might be causing this issue and/or how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Could it be that inside your resource pack under "..\assets\minecraft\textures\font" there is a file replacing the default minecraft font?

Answer (score 1):

After reading Zach K's comment, I tried deleting the font folder, as I won't be changing the font, and it fixed it. Thanks for the idea, I forgot the fonts folder existed!

> Could it be that inside your resource pack under "..\assets\minecraft\textures\font" there is a file replacing the default minecraft font?

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer with a check mark, as it makes it easier to see that the question has a working answer.